# reading excel error on configuring IIS of running asp.net application

Tags: asp.net

I am running my asp.net application on Window Server 2008.

IF I enable x86 application on ISS, it is running fine with excel 2003 files: xls

But then I got a problem of running excel 2007: (Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0). If I switch it back to x64 mode, then it is running fine with excel 2007.

So, how I config it or install something on my server in order to run both?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by always using Excel 2007 for both Excel 2003 and Excel 2007 and it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled your app for "Any CPU" it will run as a 32bit process when you set IIS to enable 32bit applications. Once your app is running as a 32 bit process, any DLLs it needs to use during execution will be expecting to see 32bit binaries; It will not be able to chop and change between 32/64 bit images once the process is running.
So, i suspect you need a 32 bit install of Excel 2007.

Comment: I'm guessing your excel 2003 is a 32 bit install already as that path works for you.